# OpenGL ES drawing with and without CCRenderTexture

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

I know I can draw OpenGL graphics with CCRenderTexture:

```
CCRenderTexture *rt = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:textureWidth height:textureHeight];
[rt beginWithClear:1, 1, 1, 1];

// OpenGL drawing like ......
ccGLEnableVertexAttribs(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position | kCCVertexAttribFlag_Color);
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);
glBlendFunc(CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)nVertices);

[rt end];
```

Without CCRenderTexture, it seems to be OK, too:

```
// OpenGL drawing like ......
ccGLEnableVertexAttribs(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position | kCCVertexAttribFlag_Color);
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);
glBlendFunc(CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)nVertices);
```

What is the difference about OpenGL drawing with and without CCRenderTexture?

Comment: you get a reusable texture in the first instance

Comment: In addition, could I say that we draw on the CCRenderTexture, then CCRenderTexture draw to frame buffer? Without CCRenderTexture, we draw to frame buffer directly? If so, CCRenderTexture is something like the concept of "off-screen"?

Comment: Yes, CCRenderTexture is like a buffer where you can draw things.